AC stops blowing cool air when it gets hot outside
I have a 2016 Acura TLX and the AC been giving me some issues lately. The AC blows cool air on a cold start but after driving for a bit under the hot summer sun, the AC stops blowing cool air. It's just warm air blowing through.
I also notice a rattling noise under the hood that come on for like 5 seconds and then stops.
The compressor and the relay was just replaced and it works fine when the temperature is around under 25 degrees but for above 30 degrees it really struggles.
Here is a link to a video I made with the different noises. At 11 seconds and 27 seconds you can here the rattling.
https://youtu.be/q1wi3X6PtiQ?si=XCgAil-qbc9ooVsv
Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated.
Thank You

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

A leak may be the original problem and still there. Remove one or both ac service port caps and look for dye and oil. Dye is greenish yellow. An inexpensive uv blacklight with car in shade, garage or night time can help find leaks; condenser coil, all hoses, fittings, compressor, connections in firewall. The rattling may be from the compressor as loss of refrigerant means less lubricating oil returns to continuously lube it. Does the cooling fan(s) run when ac runs? I'm presuming 25C/77F, 30C/86F.

Just wanted to give an update.
So I went to an AC shop and turns out there was too much freon in the system causing the pressure to go up significantly. The freon level was brought back to spec and the AC been working fine.
